# Calculate UILabel height depending on text Length for different screen sizes inside UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I am using the below code for calculate the `UILabel` `height` depending on the text it holds, it works fine, it also gives different results when i ran the code on different screen sizes, But when my UITable view loads by default height, but if i scroll it then gets updated. What should i be adding for my values to be updated when my UITable View loads ?

My code:

```
    messageOneLbl.numberOfLines = 0
    messageOneLbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    messageOneLbl.text = messageOne
    messageOneLbl.sizeToFit()
    print("one label height is \(messageOneLbl.frame.height)")
```

Above code Alaways prints same value for all iPhone screen size, I was expecting smaller value for bigger devices.

Comment: why would you expect the height to be different for different devices?

Comment: Because different width screens will hold different length strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code posted in the question is perfectly fine, Also add the height constraint to have greater than or equal to >= (what ever value you need). which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like,

```
  func heightForLabel(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{

    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGFloat.max))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text

    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}
```

Call this function and it will  return the height and set that height to your label.

Second thing it's depends on your label's initial height , width and font and on text string. So, manage your case likewise!

Answer (score 0):

It will depend in the way you are using the `Autolayout` properties in the Interface Builder, if you want to have a variable height label only set the `left`, `rigth` and `top` constraint to locate your label and `label.numberOfLines = 0`